# Filter data in Excel based on column values matched to another column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have this fairly easy to understand task but I can't figure out how this works in Excel.
I have a datasheet with a column (say ID, ranging from 1 to 10). On a second sheet I have a column (say SourceID, ranging from 5 to 20). I want to filter/display all data in the first datasheet where ID is also in the list of SourceID. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Create a further column with a match, wrapped in if,  wrapped in iferror, to return a true or false

Like

=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A$1:A$20,0),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)

Then filter on this column=true